# Android - Gridview Lag

Tags: java, android, gridview, lag

I've seen more people with the same problem as me and i've tried some of the proposed solutions but nothing worked so far.

I have a `gridView` with images (and a small title below) that are stored in the internal memory (initially they were stored in the SD Card but then i changed it because i thought the error could be resolved).

I think i need to improve the efficiency of `getView()` method. Does anyone spot the error causing the lag ?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if(v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Beer item = (Beer)getItem(position);

            picture.setImageBitmap(decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(item.photoPath, 150, 150));
            name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the View Holder pattern.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        DataHolder holder = null;

        if(holder == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            holder = new DataHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        }
        else{
            holder = (DataHolder) v.getTag();
        }
            v.setTag(holder)
holder.picture.setImageBitmap(decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(item.photoPath, 150, 150));
            holder.name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

static class DataHolder{
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But the lag continues... You forgot to instantiate `Beer item = (Beer)getItem(position);`. I did it after `DataHolder holder = null;` and instead of `row.findViewById'` i've changed it to `v.findViewById`.